# CSS: Adjust body padding without effecting background padding?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have:

```css
body
{
    background-image:url('images/background');
    background-color:#000;
    background-position:center; 
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    padding-right: 75px;
    padding-left: 75px; 
}
```

How can I get the background to act more like this:

```css
body
{
    background-image:url('images/background');
    background-color:#000;
    background-position:center; 
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

while still having padding for things within the body other than the background?

Basically, I want the background to not be effected by the padding settings, unlike the text, images, etc set within the body.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but a background won't move because of padding. Only if you set margin (and thus actually _move_ the element) will the background move with it. Padding not so much.

Comment: Currently I have a plain white background with both left and right sides being just a simple black stripe. I want the text, images, etc to show only within the white area so I set the margin wider than the black border but some reason when I view the page the background image is also effected and out of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange things a little, so you have a new top-level container within your body, so that...

```
<body ...background goes here ...>
  <div id="therealbody" ... padding goes here ...> ... content here ... </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where, or should I say how, exactly would I put the CSS tags within that div tag?

Comment: @JeremyQuick: You apply the styles to `#therealbody`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) property to take care of the padding as well as margins